# How to use Spring Data CouchBase 'findAll(Iterable<ID>)' Method?

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to use Spring-Data-Couchbase.

I want to get List from findAll(Iterable) method.
I set view 'all' to my Production View.

But, I meet the exception.
How Can I use findAll(Iterable) method?

Below is a Sample Code and exception.

Document Class:

```
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String userSeq;
}
```

Repository Class :

```
public interface UserRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<User, String> {
}
```

Service Class:

```
//List<String> get the Same result & exception.
Set<String> friendSet = new HashSet<String>();
friendSet.add("User8");
friendSet.add("User6");

userRepository.findAll(friendSet)
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: OperationException: SERVER: bad_request Reason: invalid UTF-8 JSON: {{error,{2,"lexical error: invalid char in json text.\n"}},
                 "[User8, User6]"}
at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.waitForAndCheckOperation(HttpFuture.java:98)
at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.get(HttpFuture.java:82)
at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.get(HttpFuture.java:72)
at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.query(CouchbaseClient.java:778)
... 66 more
Caused by: OperationException: SERVER: bad_request Reason: invalid UTF-8 JSON: {{error,{2,"lexical error: invalid char in json text.\n"}},
                 "[User8, User6]"}
at com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.NoDocsOperationImpl.parseError(NoDocsOperationImpl.java:110)
at com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.ViewOperationImpl.handleResponse(ViewOperationImpl.java:68)
at com.couchbase.client.http.HttpResponseCallback.completed(HttpResponseCallback.java:103)
at com.couchbase.client.http.HttpResponseCallback.completed(HttpResponseCallback.java:51)
at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:115)
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequester$RequestExecutionCallback.completed(HttpAsyncRequester.java:376)
at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:115)
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.BasicAsyncClientExchangeHandler.responseCompleted(BasicAsyncClientExchangeHandler.java:179)
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:349)
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:267)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultHttpClientIODispatch.onInputReady(DefaultHttpClientIODispatch.java:165)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultHttpClientIODispatch.onInputReady(DefaultHttpClientIODispatch.java:51)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:113)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:584)
... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the id:s before you call `findAll(...)`.

```
    Set<String> friendSet = new HashSet<String>();
    friendSet.add("\"User8\"");
    friendSet.add("\"User6\"");
```

If the id:s aren't quoted the keys parameter sent to the Couchbase server will look something like [User8, User6] which isn't valid JSON, hence the exception. Pretty surprising behaviour...